# Loucst_Plugins selenium driver is casuing multiple sessions in selenium grid

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, locust

When I launch a test all the sessions are filled up for the browser for selenium grid. I would like to see one sessions per worker. Is there anyway to accomplish this using locust_plugins and selenium.

I was expecting to see one session created per worker.